# How can I show a list of posts using the dynamic selection box?

Tags: archives

I want to use the Select Box to make a separate archives by year and month.

The list of articles for the year selected in the first selection box is divided into months in the second selection box.

And if I choose a month in the second, I want to go to the monthly list.

I searched a lot of code, but I couldn't find the right one.
Do you have any code or plug-ins to refer to?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you select month selection box you can generate WP [year archive link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_year_link/) OR [month archive link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_month_link/)

I think [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/378127/archive-filtering-posts-by-year-and-month#answer-378136) will help you.